# Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'Data'

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am trying to build a video recorder app where after recording a video, I can upload the file to aws S3. I am having problems using the uploadData() function inside my video recording app.

I'm using the camerakit-ios library (https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-ios) and the aws-amplify ios library.

I modified the handleSave function by using it to call another function uploadData(), which I referenced from here (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/storage).

I'm receiving an error `Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'Data'` in my handleSave() function. I know that it's because the format is wrong, but I'm really new to using the iOS and AWS S3 libraries together. How should I implement this?

```
class VideoPreviewViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    @IBAction func handleSave(_ sender: Any) {
        if let url = self.url {
            uploadData(data: self.url) //ERROR: Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'Data'
        }
    }

    func uploadData(data: Data) {

//        let data: Data = Data() // Data to be uploaded

        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
        expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                // Do something e.g. Update a progress bar.
            })
        }

        var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
        completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                // Do something e.g. Alert a user for transfer completion.
                // On failed uploads, `error` contains the error object.
            })
        }

        let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

        transferUtility.uploadData(data,
                                   bucket: "YourBucket",
                                   key: "YourFileName",
                                   contentType: "text/plain",
                                   expression: expression,
                                   completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
                                    (task) -> AnyObject! in
                                    if let error = task.error {
                                        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    }

                                    if let _ = task.result {
                                        // Do something with uploadTask.
                                    }
                                    return nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the `Data` from the `URL`

```
   if let url = self.url,
      let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
         uploadData(data: data)
    }
```

This syntax is reasonable if the URL is local, for a remote URL you need an asynchronous API.